# Auth0 createUser API reactJS w/ Express Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, auth0, createuser

I’m just learning how to hook up my ReactJS frontend to a Node.JS /Express backend, using the Auth0 SDK.

So far, so good in terms of creating users and adding user_metadata / user_appdata via the Auth0 console and User Management API; but I would like to allow my website Admins to create users from a frontend form via the Auth0 API.

I can’t find any code samples or tutorial videos to help me get on the right track. Feeling kinda lost right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Carlos

Comment: [get started](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/manage-users-using-the-management-api) and [specs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Akber Iqbal - I previously reviewed the Get Started docs/specs and I was able to successfully generate an API Token via node.js. I was also able to create a user via the test console on the "specs" page. However, I am not sure how to go about sending data from the frontend (via form input) and insert the data in the body of the POST request to /api/v2/users

Comment: this is subjective, but I would: (1) call my BE from FE (with form data); (2) in my BE, I will get token for managementAPI, then call `/api/v2/users` with the data that I got from my FE;